# CSS: align accordion in the center of the page

Tags: css, accordion

Today's question : how do i vertically align that *#@$¤<ç~&# accordion in the very center of my page (align it vertically & horizontally)?
here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6Zyj/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
myUl = $("ul");
myUl.css('position', 'absolute');
myUl.css('top', $(window).height() / 2 - myUl.height() / 2);  
myUl.css('left', $(window).width() / 2 - myUl.width() / 2);
```

Result: **http://jsfiddle.net/z6Zyj/2/**.

If you want a CSS only solution, you must do something as:

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: -295px;
}
```

Where `45px` is approximately half the height of your accordion and `245px` is half the width of it.

Result: **http://jsfiddle.net/z6Zyj/3/**.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrapped the whole accordion div in a 1x1 table and center aligned the table. Make the table width the same as the accordion width.